# Can't download bitcoind mac

Tags: bitcoind

I can't seem to find the `bitcoind` binaries for Mac--just the bitcoin-qt GUI application. Can someone give me a link, please?

Comment: The binary is the same, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download git and clone it from the repository. you can find instructions here:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md